# EF Core group by problem, duplicated rows

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

The problem is that when the method runs, it creates rows for the `CariHareket` table, no matter how many rows of the tables linked to the `Kontrat`.

I can't group by because EF Core doesn't support it (EF Core v3.1.9)

```
hareketService.GetAll(Predicate())//table name is CariHareket
                       .Include(s => s.Cari)
                       .Include(s => s.HedefHareketCariVirman)
                       .Include(s => s.HareketCari)
                       .Include(s => s.Kontrat).ThenInclude(s => s.KontratKalemler)
                       .Include(s => s.Kontrat).ThenInclude(s => s.KontratTarihBaglantilar)
                       .Include(s => s.Kontrat).ThenInclude(s => s.FaturaTalimativeTurkceFatura)
                       .Include(s => s.Kontrat).ThenInclude(s => s.AraciCari)
```

`CariHareket` and `Kontrat` model classes:

```
public class CariHareket
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    [ForeignKey(nameof(CariID))]
    public virtual Cariler Cari { get; set; }
    public int? CariID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(KontratID))]
    public virtual KontratUst Kontrat { get; set; }
    public int? KontratID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(HareketCariID))]
    public virtual Cariler HareketCari { get; set; }
    public int? HareketCariID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(HedefHareketCariVirmanID))]
    public virtual Cariler HedefHareketCariVirman { get; set; }
    public int? HedefHareketCariVirmanID { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Kontrat 
{
    ...
    [InverseProperty("Kontrat")]
    public virtual BindingList<KontratMasraflarNotlar> KontratMasraflarNotlar { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Kontrat")]
    public virtual BindingList<KontratKalem> KontratKalemler { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Kontrat")]
    public virtual BindingList<KontratTarihBaglantilar> KontratTarihBaglantilar { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Kontrat")]
    public virtual BindingList<KontratKasa> KontratKasa { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Kontrat")]
    public virtual BindingList<KontratKonteyner> KontratKonteyner { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Kontrat")]
    public virtual BindingList<KontratTurkceFaturaKalem> FaturaTalimativeTurkceFatura { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I do not see group by query.

Comment: because Ef Core 3 not allowed to group by @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: What can is say. If you did not specify how you wan to group - no answer. EF has limitations for grouping and sometime better do client-side grouping.

Comment: Can you rephrase the issue or give examples?

Comment: i fixed the issue installing EntityFrameoworkCore.Relational package, after 2 days researching, not the best soluation, but it is better then before.